# Is there a library or a way to implement 'the background drag'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

I want to create a background with Google Maps' fucntionallity.
So here is the idea:
[image: The screen user can drag is in center (fullscreen). When he drags - the items out the bounds apper in the center]

I haven't found any library but I guess it can be solved by css grid.
Can you help me with a piece of advice or just to say how theoretically it can be solved?

Comment: I think it's called 'touch gesture'... something like https://zingchart.github.io/zingtouch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). What you can do is have a container `div` with the `overflow` set to hidden and have a draggable image (your background) inside:

```js
 $("#draggable img").draggable();
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  margin-top: -400px;
  margin-left: -400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"> 
  <span class="move" id="draggable">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/1600/1600" class="image"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

If the snippet doesn't work here is the same code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/h3y0v4as/7/).

Comment: That was the right thing I was looking for, thanks!